# How to solve $(y''')^3-xy'''+y''=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to solve this example:

$$(y''')^3-x\cdot y'''+y''=0$$

This ODE is third order, but, what to do with the power: $^3$???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NAME y'' as t. then the equation reduces to calirut form. I am sure you can take it from there.

Comment: Try a polynomial of third degree for y(x) and notice that the general solution of an ODE of order three must contain three arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious (and helpful) substitution would be to substitute $v=y''$ to reduce the ODE to first-order:
$$(v')^3-xv'+v=0$$
Notice that you can put it in the form of a [Clairaut Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut's_equation) if you rearrange it:
$$v=xv'-(v')^3$$
Alternatively, if you prefer Leibniz notation:
$$v(x)=x\cdot \frac{dv}{dx}-\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^3$$

---

The next step would thus be to differentiate both sides wrt. $x$:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=x\cdot \frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}+\frac{dv}{dx}-3\cdot \left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^2\cdot \frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}$$
If you factor this, you should get:
$$\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}\left(x-3\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^2\right)=0$$
Therefore, you should solve for the following separately:
$$\begin{cases} \frac{d^2v}{dx^2}=0 \\ x-3\cdot \left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^2=0 \end{cases}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand and get the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: notice that this is not THE general solution (as stated before) but it is general within the class of analytic functions. See section 2. for another class.

1. As proposed in a comment we can try the ansatz

$$y(x)=a x^3+b x^2+c x+d$$

This gives us the

Then the ODE gives just one relation between the coefficients, viz.

$$b\to -108 a^3$$

so that

$$y(x) =a x^3-108 a^3 x^2+c x+d$$

is a solution.

And it is even the general solution as in contains three arbitrary constants $a$, $c$, and $d$. These can be used to adapt the solution to initial conditions thus: $$y(0)=d, y'(0)=c, y''(0)=-216 a^3$$

2. The power Ansatz

$$y(x) = r x^w$$

leads to

$$w \to \frac{7}{2}, r\to \pm \frac{8}{105 \sqrt{3}} $$

We observe that an integer power in $\sqrt{x}$ appears.

Notice that you can always add a general linear polynomial to $y(x)$

Comment: We got the same solution, thank you! :)